# Change the error message "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

When a user submits a content that has a taxonomy selection field and *NOT* make a selection, then the referenced error appears.

Now, I know exactly when, how and where the message appears, is there any way to change it so that it's actually useful for the user (i.e. "You did not select a category."), and not merely a cryptic error message that could potentially freak the user out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add custom validation to the node, so that you can control the error message that get's output. There's an excellent example of that [in this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/how-to-validate-node-field-for-minimum-length-for-a-custom-content-type). A potential problem with this is that you *may* now get both error messages. I don't immediately have a suggestion for how to deal with that.

Comment: Okay, I was actually being lazy--I knew this was one way to go about it (and in fact, did this for other errors), but I didn't want to roll yet *another* custom validator. I was hoping there was an easier way.

I'll submit my own answer and provide a way to remove the cryptic message and only show the error that should be shown.

Answer (score 6):

This is to add onto Letharion's answer. Using the same principle, we can also check for error messages to replace in the validator.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_validate($form, &$form_state){
    $errors = drupal_get_messages(); // (dpm()'s has to go AFTER this line--they get cleared)
    foreach ($errors as $type => $id) {
        foreach ($id as $message){
            // Loop through individual messages, looking for ones to remove or replace
            if (test_for_invalid_error($message)===FALSE){
                drupal_set_message($message,$type);
            } elseif (test_for_invalid_error($message)!==TRUE){
                drupal_set_message(test_for_invalid_error($message), $type);
            }
        }
    }
}

function test_for_invalid_error($message){
    if (strpos($message, 'An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.') !== false) {
        return t('Please select a category!');
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

This will not only add your own custom error, but replace the "An illegal choice" error. Isn't it neat? Yay!

Answer (score 1):

The module [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)
 will be yours best solution ,
just change the string for what ever you like.

Comment: That would replace the text string globally, potentially giving a _very_ confusing error message in every single other situation where this message is used.

Comment: ok , but it give him the chance to write some other message for the user that will not freak the user out.

Comment: I see what you mean, but disagree with your conclusion. Later, a user will make a mistake with say, a Views exposed filter, Views tries to output the same error message, the user get's an error message that's about taxonomy terms, and is only useful in the context of node-edit forms. Now _that_ will freak out the user. In my opinion, this solution, will multiply the problem, instead of remove it.

Comment: got your point.