# How to auto submit only after typing at least three character in view exposed filter

Tags: views

I have a view with exposed filters using AJAX and auto-submit feature.

The problem is it reacts to every char I type but what I want is that when a user type at least three character in the text field then it should auto submit and display search result. But Cant figure out how to implement this. Please help

Comment: It's not clear, how many ajax request should be send if you type 6 chars? (2, after 3 and after 6 char, or 4 after 3, 4, 5 and 6 char)

Comment: @kala4ek If I type 6 chars it should send 4 ajax request. say If I search for drupal, It sould send ajax request for (dru, drup, drupa, drupal)

Answer (score 0):

- Attach ***custom_form_validate*** for that form using
  ***form_alter***
- Do what ever you want in this custom_validation.
- [Reference](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6951/how-to-validate-node-field-for-minimum-length-for-a-custom-content-type)